# Temporary tables in influxdb

Tags: influxdb

Is there a way to create temporary tables in influxdb for a specific query? (so that their scope is just that query, versus creating and inserting into a new measurement).

I thought about writing a continuous query, but there are [restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579608/continuous-queries-in-influxdb-ignoring-where-clause) on the where clause (namely the the time), that CQs don't allow and that I need. And the semantics of a CQ isn't really what I'm looking for anyways.

My use case: I'm working mainly with historical time series data. I have an expensive query to retrieve values for a set of stock tickers over a certain period of time. I'd like to use these as intermediate results to then calculate aggregates over different time granularities (daily/weekly etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no temporary views in InfluxDB 0.9 as of now. Please open a feature request on GitHub and describe your use case: https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/new

Comment: will do. Thank you. Accepting as answer.